# Error with android:clickColor when defining a style

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to define a style this way in the /values/styles.xml file:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.test" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:clickColor">@android:color/red</item>
</style>
```

But, the eclipse shows me an error on the last line of the style tag with the text: 
`error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:clickColor'.`

I found somewhere that I might need to have the build target up to 13. In my application i have the following lines in the AndroiManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Any idea what is causing the problem?

Comment: Try to fix project properties, also a clean project can fix it.

Comment: I use selectors for this

Comment: @RotaryHeart: Cleaned the project and nothing...

Comment: @NarendraPal: How to use selectors to change the color of the text? Can you, please, show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you try every possibilities and finally also its not working then you may go for this

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="....."/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color=".........."/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="..........."/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: I think there isn't a `android:color` atrribute in the `<item>` tag

Comment: you can use selector for changing the color if you have any doubt then you may go for this link..             http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But, I really want to know what's the problem with the `android:clickColor`